# wildfly is not uploading large file

Tags: configuration, httpd.conf, wildfly-10, apache2.2, large-file-upload

Here is my Standalone.xml connector configurations

```
            <server name="default-server">
            <ajp-listener name="ajp-ofs" socket-binding="ajp" scheme="https"/>
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-post-size="100000000" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/images" handler="images"/>
                <location name="/js" handler="js"/>
                <location name="/css" handler="css"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```

and here are socket bindings

```
   <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
```

problem is when I upload a file on my local window machine it works fine but on other machines it is not entertaining

> max-post-size="100000000"
>   any suggestion or any possibility.    **its surprise for me their is proxy, webservices** are called from a Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) and Apache is connected to wildfly10.0.1Final by mode_jk. For mode_jk we are using ajp listeners i have added max-post-size="100000000" in ajp listener and max-ajp-packet-size= "100000000" in ajp listener. but not succeed

Comment: please suggest me solution. I have wasted a lot of time already.

Comment: may be your server locate behind a proxy (nginx and etc) and this proxy has its own post size restriction

Comment: thanks for reply CyberWasp, it is working well on a local machine but on live environment its creating problem with same configurations.

Comment: and their is no proxy .

Comment: @CyberWasp yes its surprise for me their is proxy, webservices are called from a Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) and Apache is connected to wildfly10.0.1Final by mode_jk. For mode_jk we are using ajp listeners i have added max-post-size="100000000" in ajp listener and max-ajp-packet-size= "100000000" in ajp listener. but not succeed

Comment: @CyberWasp                                                                                              `<ajp-listener name="ajp-ofs" socket-binding="ajp" scheme="https" max-post-size="100000000" />`                                          
or   `<ajp-listener name="ajp-ofs" socket-binding="ajp" scheme="https" max-ajp-packet-size= "100000000" />`  but no success

Comment: I don't use apache and jmod, but may be problem in apache settings. Like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/875437/cant-increase-max-post-size-in-apache2)

Comment: plelase help me.

Comment: I try setup locally apache2 and mod_jk. All works if I set max-post-size in ajp-listener. May be there are another proxy before apache? May be load balancer?